# With the code below I receive the error Variable not defined

Tags: vba, excel, date

Columns A, D and E are date and time.

I am trying to find out how many times the date in Column A falls between the start dates and end dates.

Column A may vary between 30 and 60 days while the start and end dates run to thousands.

Two questions:

1. Why am I receiving error Variable Not defined with the code below?
2. If cell A2 is date and time 24Feb17 12H00 then what formula do I put in cell A3 so that it reads 25Feb17 12H00 and so on?

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DaysCount()
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ICount As Long
    Dim Day() As Variant
    Dim StartDate() As Variant
    Dim EndDate() As Variant
    ICount = 0
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        endRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        Day = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        StartDate = Sheet1.Range("D2:D" & endRow)
        EndDate = Sheet1.Range("E2:E" & endRow)

        For i = LBound(StartDate) To UBound(StartDate)
            For J = LBound(Day) To UBound(Day)
                If Day(J, 1) >= StartDate(i, 1) And Day(J, 1) <= EndDate(i, 1) Then
                    ICount = ICount + 1
                Else

                End If
                Sheet1.Range("B" & J).Value = ICount
            Next i
            ICount = 0
        Next J
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Option Explicit` at the top of the code means that you need to declare ALL variables used in the code e.g. `Dim i as integer` has not been included, nor has variable `j`

Comment: Which line create `ERROR`?

Comment: Because you have Option Explicit set and variable i and j are not defined. But there are more issues with the code, for example with the `next i` statement before `next j` statement

Comment: @harun24hr Thank you for identifying my rookie error, I have now defined i and j as variables but now I receive the error "Invalid Next Control Variable Reference" Can you help me with this?

Comment: @FunThomas Thank you for identifying my rookie error, I have now defined i and j as variables but now I receive the error "Invalid Next Control Variable Reference" Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Anthony: You have to close the inner loop (the one using j) before you close the outer (using i). For every iteration of i, do a full loop with j. Probably you just have to exchange i and j at the `next` statement, but I havn't digged deeper into you code.

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks I managed to sort this out but you are right in that I had to swap the i and the j in the If Statement. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Option Explicit` forces you to declare all variables, so you need to declare `i` and `j` too.
   And your `Next i` and `Next j` weren't in the good order!
2. VBA : `DateAdd("d",.Range("A3"),1)`

Corrected code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DaysCount()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim endRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ICount As Long
Dim Day() As Variant
Dim StartDate() As Variant
Dim EndDate() As Variant
ICount = 0
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    endRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Day = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    StartDate = Sheet1.Range("D2:D" & endRow)
    EndDate = Sheet1.Range("E2:E" & endRow)

    For i = LBound(Day) To UBound(Day)
        For j = LBound(StartDate) To UBound(StartDate)
            If Day(j, 1) >= StartDate(i, 1) And Day(j, 1) <= EndDate(i, 1) Then
                ICount = ICount + 1
            Else
            End If
        Next j
        .Range("B" & i).Value = ICount
        ICount = 0
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate your time spent helping a rookie. Big thanks!